# Degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\zeta_7)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, roots-of-unity

Question is  to compute the degree of the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\zeta_7)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

We have   $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\zeta_7):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\zeta_7):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)][\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7):\mathbb{Q}]$

As $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\zeta_7):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)]$ can be at most $2$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7):\mathbb{Q}]=6$ we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\zeta_7):\mathbb{Q}]=6$ or $12$.

I am not able to compute $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\zeta_7):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)]$..

I believe this is dead simple but i could not make it...

Hint would be sufficient..

Note : $\zeta_3$ and $\zeta_7$ are primitive third and seventh roots of unity respectively..

Comment: This would be a better question if you could explain what you mean by $\zeta_3,\zeta_7$ which look like they are third and seventh roots of unity respectively.

Comment: @MarkBennet : I should have mentioned it before... Edited... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is stated correctly, $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\zeta_7):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)]$ can be at most $2$. It suffices to show that $\zeta_3 \notin \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$. Assume it were in this field. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ would contains $\zeta_3 \zeta_7$, which is a primitive $21$-st root of unity. The degree of such a root over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\varphi(21)= 12$, a contradiction to the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ being $6$.

Indeed, you could argue like this right away: $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_3,\zeta_7) =\mathbb{Q} (\zeta_{21}) $.

Comment: I have mentioned that i need just a hint.. thank you so much :)

Comment: You are welcome. Indeed, I wondered if I should add the last sentence of the first paragraph, but then went for a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative proof:

Assuming $\zeta_3\in\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$, we have $\sqrt{-3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$, so, by Cauchy's theorem, $x^2+3$ splits over any finite field $\mathbb{F}$ such that $7\mid \#\,\mathbb{F}^*$. However, $x^2+3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{29}$, since $29\equiv -1\pmod{3}$ and $-3$ is a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{p}$ only if $p\equiv 1\pmod{3}$.

Comment: I am sorry, what cauchy theorem are you referring to?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: if $p$ is a prime number, in any group of size $pk$ there is $p$-th root of unity.

Comment: why would $x^2+3$ split over that finite field... :O Please explain  a bit more...

Comment: Because if $7\mid\#\mathbb{F}^*$, then $\phi_7(x)$ completely splits over $\mathbb{F}$. Assuming that $\zeta_3\in\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$, then $\sqrt{-3}\in\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_7)$, so in $\mathbb{F}$ there is an element whose square is $-3$, that is the same as stating that $x^2+3$ splits over $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I guess the not so easy part is why from the fact that $\sqrt{-3} \in \mathbb Q(\eta_7)$ should follow that in the finite field there is a square root of $-3$.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa: ok, assuming that, from $\sqrt{-3}=Q_1 + Q_2 \zeta_7$ it follows that $-3 = (Q_1+Q_2 \zeta_7)^2$, so any finite field containing a seventh root of unity contains a square root of $-3$, too.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio for start since $[\mathbb Q(\zeta_7):\mathbb Q]=6$ it's not so clear why $\sqrt{-3}=Q_1+Q_2\zeta_7$ and not $Q_0+Q_1\zeta_7+\dots+Q_6 \zeta_7^6$, second it's not so clear (at least not to me) why the relation $-3=(Q_1+Q_2\zeta_7)^2$, which holds in $\mathbf Q(\zeta_7)$ should also hold in the finite field $\mathbb F$.... guess I'm a little rusty on arithmetics...